# How do I make a snapshot in Windows Sandbox?

Tags: windows-10, windows-sandbox

I want to make a snapshot that I can restore to later. How do I do this within the sandbox? I have not been able to find any extensive documentation nor how to perform this one particular task.

Comment: That means Windows Sandbox uses a snapshot of your real OS, like a base image in container/docker ecosystem. This saves time by not using full OS. That does not mean we can create a snapshot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I want to make a snapshot that I can restore to later. How do I do this within the sandbox?

What you want is not possible.

> I have not been able to find any extensive documentation nor how to perform this one particular task.

You have not been able to find any documentation because it does not exist.

> Snapshot allows us to boot the sandbox environment once and preserve the memory, CPU, and device state to disk. Then we can restore the sandbox environment from disk and put it in the memory rather than booting it, when we need a new instance of Windows Sandbox. This significantly improves the start time of Windows Sandbox.

**This does not indicate the user can initiate a snapshot.**  What this quoted text is indicating is that Windows Sandbox itself creates a snapshot of your system.

Source: [Windows Sandbox](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Windows-Kernel-Internals/Windows-Sandbox/ba-p/301849)

Comment: "Snapshot allows us to boot the sandbox environment once and preserve the memory, CPU, and device state to disk. Then we can restore the sandbox environment from disk and put it in the memory rather than booting it, when we need a new instance of Windows Sandbox. This significantly improves the start time of Windows Sandbox. "

I see, so "snapshot" is perhaps an unfortunate name for this feature. Guess I'll have to use other VM software then.

Comment: @Math1000 - **Windows Sandbox is NOT a virtual machine.**  It sounds like you want to use Hyper-V, but like all hypervisors, if you are running Windows it will require it's own license.